# Typescript compilation issues

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I have a complex interface. A simpler version of it would be something like this

```
Interface Person {
'name': string, 'address': string, 'age': number, 'height': number 
}

const person:Person = {'name': 'Yair', 'address': 'here', 'age': 12, 'height': 186}
```

Now say I wanted to create a function to dynamically update the name or address. This works well:

```
let updateNameOrAddress = (key: "name"|"address", value: string): void => {
    person[key] = value
}
```

However, defining keys this way will get hard when I'll add more and more string fields. So I try something like this:

```
let updateNameOrAddress = (key: keyof Person, value: string): void => {
    person[key] = value
}
```

Well, this creates this error:
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
I have reasons to believe that this is because name can now also be "age" or "height". I'd stick to adding types as possibilities for "name" - but my real object has lots of values. Is there a way to get keyof, to retrive only the string / numberic keys?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to get keyof, to retrive only the string / numberic keys?

```js
interface Person {
  'name': string;
  'address': string;
  'age': number;
  'height': number;
}

type KeysOfType<T, U> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never
}[keyof T];

const person: Person = { 'name': 'Yair', 'address': 'here', 'age': 12, 'height': 186 }

let updateNameOrAddress = (key: KeysOfType<Person, string>, value: string): void => {
  person[key] = value
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyA5CHALYQkBcyGYUoA5gNxGlwAmXUEGGWvUYt2xEnGbU6IAK4UARtDGkAFhGDNVYIXMXKCAXwIEwATwAOKANIQzGAPIwAKpYgAeZwBpkAVQB8yAC8+BwA2tbIoMgA1nZYMMjOALp0zhHJyBAAHpAgXBh+yAD8yJEyEABu0EZhcWYJScnsBAg4DMhWUNggdOjdOMH4pORUQiQAmnDAUCQ+Ejx8AuPqfHOcUkIAjABM8+qa2tsAHABsyMYEADYQYMiyFlxwkABylBAOUACCi-yFIQAKep0Wz2JyuKzufo9HwMJggZj+HyVOBXWQQOhwlgASjolSwwC4wUChGIXR6dTsmRCKLRECMBCAA)

Answer (score 0):

Using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) you can check the changed key and map it onto `Person` to retrieve the property's value type generically.

Notice that `T` is accessing `Person[T]`, this means that the type of the `value` parameter can be determined based on the given `key` argument.

```
interface Person {
  'name': string, 'address': string, 'age': number, 'height': number
}

const person: Person = { 'name': 'Yair', 'address': 'here', 'age': 12, 'height': 186 }

const updateNameOrAddress = <T extends keyof Person>(key: T, value: Person[T]): void => {
  person[key] = value;
}

updateNameOrAddress("name", "John"); // Ok
updateNameOrAddress("age", "47"); // Error!
updateNameOrAddress("age", 47); // Ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4BQyyA5CHALYQkBcyGYUoA5gDSlwAmnUEGGteoxbsScZtTogArhQBG0UQAsIwZkrCCZ86AQC+BAghwNkAB0w466KNlwBefKXJVBJAJpxgUEqK48+AToSFV5fDglBAEYAJmVVdU06KIAOADZkAyMTMGRpM044SAA5SggAeSgAQW5efmRHAB4AFWQIAA9IEE4MZABrCABPLBg0SxAAPgAKAcG6ZvYANzgAG2kIa3GAbWaAXQBKOkWsYE4Gifwic23Z3YbkZbWIAG59Q3zCkrLKmoD+KYARC4IAD2ACAFJYJQgAH7Z7IAD0COQ5T6BA+RQgpSoP1qgUB4hBYIALAB2WHwpHIACiUCgWCgAEJ0QVMdiKtU8f8AYTQcgyXDEcjUYygA)